# Failed to open a bucket, anyone can tell me why?

Tags: node.js, couchbase, bucket

```
var couchbase = require("couchbase");


var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('127.0.0.1:8091');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('LFC', function(err) {
    if (err) {

        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Success')
});
```

Here how i connect to the bucket but when i try to open the server it says : `"Failed to connect to the bucket".`

Comment: Can you run that code but with libcouchbase [logging](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/c-2.4/logging.html) enabled and share the output please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change this line with:

```
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://localhost:8091');
```

Then try to uninstall couchbase , erase everything and install again. If you haven't created the bucket 'LFC' first create it from console. Then run your code.